# UPDATE TIME TO SQL DB

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

I have table td with contenteditable and in a cell td i want to update time in the format eg. 1230 and not 12:30. So how can i set new time without edit the two points ":"

Here my code:

```
 <table>
<?php foreach($data as $k => $v){;?>

$id = $v['id_flight'];

 <tr id="<?= $id;?>">
 <td name="arrivalTime" conteneditable="true" onblur="save(this, <?= $id;?>)"> <?= $v['time'];?> </td>

<!-- JQUERY AJAX -->
function save(t, id){
var id = $(t).closest('tr').attr('id')
var text = $(t).text()
var name = $(t).attr('name')

$.ajax({
url : 'DB/ops_update_text.php',
type: 'POST',
data: 'text=' + text + '&id=' + id + '&name=' + name,
success: function(data){
console.log(data)
}
})

<!-- PHP UPDATE -->
$host = '';  // MY DB CONNECTION
$user = '';
$pwd = '';
$dbapt = "";

$conn =  mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $dbapt);
if(!$conn){
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}

$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $_POST['text'];



 $sql = "UPDATE flights SET $name = '$text' WHERE id_flight=$id";
 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
 }
```

This blocks of code work only if in the td contenteditable i put: 12:30 but i want to insert only 1230. How can I do that?

Please help !!!!!
THX

Comment: Unrelated, but you're at risk of [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: it will be a prepared statement i m only testing the code

Comment: would you be so kind as to not use CAPS (for the title) and to change them lowercase please? It's considered as yelling (at us). @scunja *thanks*

Comment: `foreach($data as $k => $v){;` that loop will not work since the semi-colon stops the loop.

Comment: What is the DB structure? Why not use prepared statements now?

Comment: your code contains mixed languages and is unsure if you used script/php tags and closed them off.

Comment: Thank you but i cannot modify the title now... so sorry for that. The original code is on different pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the string into something you can use:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

if(($name == "arrivalTime") && (substr($text,2,1) != ":")) {
  $text = substr($text,0,2).":".substr($text,2,2);
}
```

Comment: It was a typo mistake from my side but now working fine :)